# R - Using for loop to conditionally change values in a dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop, sapply

All of the variables are on the same scale in the data.frame 1-5.

Example of data.frame

```
rpi_invert

A   B   C   D
5   2   4   1
3   5   5   2
1   1   3   4
```

For all values that equal `5` I would like to change it to `1`.

for `4` change to `2`.

for `2` change to `4`.

for `1` change to `5`.

Example of data.frame after values have been changed.

```
rpi_invert

A   B   C   D
1   4   2   5
3   1   1   4
5   5   3   2
```

What I have tired.

```
for(b in colnames(rpi_invert)){
  rpi_invert[[b]][rpi_invert[[b]] == 5] <- 1
  rpi_invert[[b]][rpi_invert[[b]] == 4] <- 2
  rpi_invert[[b]][rpi_invert[[b]] == 2] <- 4
  rpi_invert[[b]][rpi_invert[[b]] == 1] <- 5
}
```

This will only change the values in the first row and not the second column.

```
for(b in colnames(rpi_invert)){
rpi_invert <- ifelse(rpi_invert[[b]] == 5,1,
                     ifelse(rpi_invert[[b]] == 4,2,
                            ifelse(rpi_invert[[b]] == 2,4,
                                   ifelse(rpi_invert[[b]] == 1,5,rpi_invert[[b]]))))
}
```

But this gives me the error:

```
Error in rpi_invert[[b]] : subscript out of bounds
```

If I try to the same methods for an individual column instead of looping through the data.frame then both methods work so I am not sure what is the problem.

I am sure what I am trying to do can be done more efficiently without a `for loop` probably with some type of apply function but I am not sure how.

Any help will be appreciated please let me know if further information is needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try (if your data.frame is `df`):

```
3-(df-3)
#  A B C D
#1 1 4 2 5
#2 3 1 1 4
#3 5 5 3 2
```

or, same but written a bit differently: `6-df`

Comment: That's really clever.

Comment: @Cath That worked great! Your way is much more efficient. If possible do you understand why my for loops failed to do what I wanted them to do? If not I am sure I can do further research to better understand for loops.

Comment: @Dre, in your first for loop, you change the values `5` and `4` into `1` and `2` with the first 2 lines but then, you change `1`s and `2`s back into `5`s and `4`s with the last 2 lines so it cannot work. In  your second for loop, there are several problems, there are far too many embedded `ifelse`s but what causes the error is that you reassign your complete df at each "loop turn" instead of just column `rpi_invert[[b]]`

Comment: ahh that makes sense. Thank you for your answer and explanation.